# How to color (fill in) just one column (whose value in the data frame belongs to a row) of different colors using geom_bar in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill, geom-bar

In this graphic, I want the column of Peru to come out with a different color, to distinguish it from the other countries. In this case "pais" is the column that contains "Peru". I use pais$Peru  to filter the country(Peru) that is a row, but it doesn't work. I get the following result "Error in pais$Peru : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Does anyone know how to do that? how to structure my code?

MY CODE IS

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = railroad,
                    x=reorder(pais, -railroad),
                    fill=pais$Peru),
           data = jaja,
           stat = "identity")+
           guides(fill=FALSE)+  
           xlab(NULL)+ ylab(NULL)+ 
          scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,7))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50))
```

THANKSSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `scale_fill_manual` and pass a named vectors with the countries and the colors.

An Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(avg_hp = mean(hp))

# Create named vector to pass to scale_fill_manual
# Color of green for cyl of 4
# Default of 'blue' where cyl doesn't equal 4
bar_colors <- c('4' = 'green' ,setNames(rep(c('blue'), times = length(df[df$cyl!=4,]$cyl)), df[df$cyl!=4,]$cyl))

ggplot(df, aes(x= factor(cyl), y = avg_hp, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = bar_colors)
```

Results in

[image: Example Output]